# How can I get https response of a site using curl in via get request?

Tags: curl, libcurl

I got a code to perform that but why it doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main()
{
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/url2file.html");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL, "https");
  struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, stdout);
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
      if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));
}
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
return 0;
}
```

Gives the output:

> curl_easy_perform() failed: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK

but when I execute 'curl https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/url2file.html' in cmd it gives the response successfully.

I got this code from Postman and just edited a little bit.
My purpose was printing the response of the site to the stdout.

'Get' request works well on Postman, but why it doesn't on libcurl in c.
How can I solve this problem ?
I'm pretty new in libcurl and I can't find good enough information about it, So what do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that's error number 60? (Documented [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html))

It means that the CA cert libcurl uses couldn't verify the server cert from curl.haxx.se - if you enable `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` you can see what path it uses to the CA cert. You might have to point it to a specific path.

Your code also uses a lot of superfluous options you can remove :

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
```

That's the default

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL, "https");
```

That's only interesting when you specify "URLs" without a scheme, which you didn't!

```
struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
```

This has no effect.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, stdout);
```

This is the default anyway.